# php, echo doesn't show after form post?

Tags: php, cookies

i have a form and when i post it i create a cookie, then i read the cookie and if isset then do something:

inside `read.php`

```
    <?php if (isset($_COOKIE['voteforme'])) { 
echo 'You voted this profile';
} else {?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="vote_points" id="vote_points" value="1000" />
<input type="submit" name="votes_send" id="votes_send" value="Vote for me" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

then i do some cookie creation inside 'create.php':

```
if (isset($_POST['votes_send'])){
$get_vote_for_me = $_POST['vote_points'];
$get_talent_id = $_POST['talent_id'];
$value1 = "voteforme";
$value2 = "voteforme_points";
setcookie($value1,$value2, time()+3600*24*7);
}
```

this script is creating the cookie i need. basically if the cookie `$_COOKIE['voteforme']` is set then show a message, else show the form.

the problem i have is that i need to refresh the page a second time for the page to read the cookie and see if exists or not.

the file structure is  `index.php` where i include the `read.php` and 'create.php'

any ideas??

thanks

edit:
even if i set the form action to any of those files the result is the same

edit, `index.php` structure:

```
<?php 
require_once("read.php");
include 'create.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>...
<body>...
<div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
<?php  read();?> // the read.php it's a function
</div>
...
```

the `read.php` i am requiring it it at the top but i'm not actually calling git until inside the body as a function

adit:
i've also tried to add the `setcookie` inside the `else` statement inside the 'read.php', but there it doesn't get created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check for the cookie set after you set the cookie?  Then proceed to update your page.  You just can't print anything to the page before doing your cookie work.

Another solution would be to use javascript to reduce the number of reloads.

A third idea would be to use a global variable which you can check in addition to the cookie -- that way if you set the cookie you would execute the appropriate code based on the global variable.

Comment: this is the way i have it setup. the `create.php` file is first inline

Comment: can you put up a barebones structure of your index.php file, then I can see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: I think you need to separate the check for the cookie from the actual form read() function so you can perform it in the head, before the doctype tag.  You can track if your cookie has been set and use that to determine how to build your form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you separate the files. POST data to create.php and add a redirection in create.php back to index.php. This way page will load and it will be able to read your cookie.

or you could try this, if not done already:

first include create.php and then read.php

Answer (score 0):

setcookie() doesn't set the value in $_COOKIE immediately, it'll only be there after the client sends another request with the cookie. You can set it manually if you want.

Comment: well, first i check for a cookie that doesn't exists, then, i submit the form (the page refreshes) and i create one cookie. if i check the cookies i can see it. but the form doesn't see it.